# How react works with javascript ui components that modifies html

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, reactjs, kendo-ui

most javascript ui components, like jquery ui, bootstrap or kendo ui takes some html element and renders itself dynamically.

Someting like this:

```
$('#someselect').autocomplete();
```

I wonder if these frameworks can be effectively used with react.

Let's say, I would like to wrap such component into react component. When component state changes, e.g. SelectedValue, react rerenders the html. but since the html is just some container where the javascript ui components renders itself(e.g autocomplete), it's not very effective.

Can react be effectively used with most javascript ui components or they have to be built with react-like rendering in mind

Comment: you can mix and match react with other stuff, but not blend easily if that makes sense.. also I don't see any good reason to do so.

Comment: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/jquery-with-react/683/5

Answer (score 0):

This article ["Working with the Browser"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html) from the react documentation discusses this.

Using operating on the DOM directly using something like jQuery is not considered good practice for a few reasons:

- React intentionally discourages using DOM attributes as selectors with the rationale that tracing props down through the component hierarchy is more scalable.
- These plugins don't make use of React's event lifecycle. You would have functionality that was dependent on the DOM being fully mutated, and others that were regular react components.

Still, If necessary you can perform operations on the DOM with something like jQuery inside of `componentDidMount`.

Here's an example of using [React with jQuery UI Sortable](https://gist.github.com/petehunt/7882164).